# Divs Not Acting Responsively in Browser

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage

Have 3 floated divs thatI have set to act responsively. It works fine in the live view of dreamweaver but not when testing in browsers. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pa5Ey/

CSS

```
#maincontentInner{
    max-width:1170px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #999999;
    border-left-color: #999999;
    padding-top:50px;
    }

.3col {
    width: 32.26%;
    margin-right:1.6%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and the Markup

```
<div class="3col" style="margin-left:1.9%">
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
    </div>

    <div class="3col">
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
    </div>

    <div class="3col">
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
        Some Text Here<br />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"/>

  </div><!-- End maincontentInner -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by "act responsively"? Would you mind being more precise on the expected behavior?

Comment: Apologies. I want the divs to flex with broswer resizing and eventually stack on top of each other. I've had success with this method before, but not for this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS does not allow class names that begin with a number. The first character MUST be a letter.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa5Ey/3/)

```
.threecol {
    width: 32%;
    margin-right:1%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Width and margin doesn't work with decimals 
So the right code will be:

```
.threecol {
    width: 32%;
    margin-right:1%;
}
```

Comment: Actually, decimal places in percentages do work, as long as the resulting computed value is different from the absolute value of the percentage. In other words, 32.5% of 200px is 65px, whereas 32% of 200px is 64px. The 32.5% would be honored in this case, and result in a different value than 32%. Browsers tend to round values that cannot be logically displayed, such as a half pixel difference. Using a decimal in percentages is allowed.